# Expectation with indicator function $E[I(X > 0)e^{X}]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, self-learning, expected-value

How do we compute the expectation of:
$$E[I(X > 0)e^{X}]$$
where X is a standard normal?
the expectation of $e^X$ is $e^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and that of $I(X > 0)$ is $\frac{1}{2}$ but how do I bring is together?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the definition of expectation, complete the square, do a change a variable and express it in terms of CDF of standard normal distribution.

\begin{align}
E[I(X>0)e^X] &= \int_0^\infty e^x  \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\, dx \\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left( -\frac{x^2-2x}2\right) \, dx \\
&= \int_0^\infty \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left( -\frac{(x-1)^2-1}2\right) \, dx \\
&= e^\frac12\int_0^\infty \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left( -\frac{(x-1)^2}2\right) \, dx \\
&= e^{\frac12} \int_{-1}^\infty \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left( -\frac{x^2}2\right) \, dx \\
&= e^\frac12 Pr(Z > -1)\\
\end{align}